# gcc compiles ELF file with wrong search list

Tags: c, gcc, ld, elf, linux-from-scratch

After compiling gcc and using it to compile a simple c program:

```
echo 'int main(){}' > dummy.c
cc dummy.c -v -Wl,--verbose &> dummy.log
grep -B4 '^ /usr/include' dummy.log
```

the result is:

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/tools/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/tools/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include
```

but according to [Linux From Scratch guide 9.1 in section 6.25](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/gcc.html) "Verify that the compiler is searching for the correct header files:" the following is expected (ignoring the *linux-gnu paths...):

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
```

What's even worse is that

```
grep 'SEARCH.*/usr/lib' dummy.log |sed 's|; |\n|g'
```

is:

```
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib");
```

but should be:

```
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib");
```

I've tried to add all paths to /etc/ld.so.conf and recompiled gcc pass 2, but nothing changed.

So what exactly determines the SEARCH_DIR entries in an ELF file?

EDIT1: I backtracked and found out that the previous step make -k clean did not finish because it's missing autogen, which is not covered at all in the LFS guide 9.1 it seems.

Comment: Your `grep` pattern searches for lines starting with a blank and continuing with `/usr/include`.  There's only one such line — it was reported.  You won't see `/usr/local/include` because your search excludes it (or doesn't select it).

Comment: Your `grep` is fine, it is the correct command from the book. The idea is to match the line `^ /usr/include`, then return 4 lines before it (i.e. `-B4`) to verify the correct include paths. Your output here should match what the book says, don't continue until it does. You will need to retrace your steps and figure out what you did wrong. http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter01/askforhelp.html Sorry I can't be of more help, you might try the mailing lists.

Comment: One possible cause... did you pass `+h` to `bash` when you ran `chroot` so that hashing is turned off? Here is the end of a thread that seems to match your issue: http://lists.linuxfromscratch.org/pipermail/lfs-support/2008-July/034656.html

Comment: Yep, did +h for the chroot. Thanks for mentioning the help section.

Comment: Are you confusing search directories for include directives with search directories for libraries? They are entirely different concepts. Please clarify.

Comment: Possibly, but I shared the commands that produce the output. So you should be able to tell what's wrong.

Comment: There is no `make -k clean` step. `Augogen` isn't needed, it isn't even part of BLFS. You don't need to add anything to `/etc/ld.so.conf ` except what you're instructed to add in section **6.9.2.3. Configuring the Dynamic Loader**. Your output should match what the book says. If it does not, that means you've made a mistake following the directions. Even if you're able to finesse `GCC` into giving you what you want now, that doesn't mean your toolchain is correct. Go back to the beginning of **Chapter 6**, if not page 1, and start over. There are no shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted LFS 9.1 and followed the instruction with more care, now the output is as expected!

There are two things I did differently:

1. In my first attempt I ignored the advice on [chapter 5](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/generalinstructions.html) to remove extracted tarballs after each section:

> For each package:
>
> 1. Using the tar program, extract the package to be built. In Chapter 5, ensure you are the lfs user when extracting the package.
> 2. Change to the directory created when the package was extracted.
> 3. Follow the book's instructions for building the package.
> 4. Change back to the sources directory.
> 5. **Delete the extracted source directory unless instructed otherwise.**

2. When I reinstalled the host OS I didn't create it with *lfs* as first user. Instead I created it with *lfshost* user and created the user *lfs* as described in [section 4.3](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/addinguser.html)